# After installation, Ubuntu 16 will not boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, hard-drive

My computer has 2 Nvidia graphics cards, and I have Windows running on one SATA drive.

I added a second SATA drive, just plugged it in via the 2 cables.  I attempted to install Ubuntu 16 on the second SATA drive.  It came up on the screen just fine, installed on the drive, and asked me to reboot.

Upon reboot, I remove the USB stick and set the Ubuntu-installed SATA drive as the primary boot drive.  After Bios, nothing happens.  I only get a blank screen, and the computer does not even seem to be working on anything, no blinking lights or anything.  It just seems to be frozen there.

When I press the power button the computer shuts down instantly, no 10-second press or anything.

How can I get Ubuntu to work?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are both installs UEFI or both BIOS? Do you now get grub, you should if both drives are the same. Otherwise you need Escape right after UEFI screen to get grub or shift key after BIOS screen. You probably need nomodeset until you install nVidia proprietary driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? or Ubuntu Core 16?. The latter (Ubuntu Core 16) has no desktop, fewer drivers, being intended for IoT appliances and is usually used headless (no display), ie. Ubuntu Core 16 is a specialist release which is why it has the *year* format instead of the usual *year.month* format of standard releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you verify that the drives are both ok on a windows machine, or on your linux machine. Try each of them separately before you try them together.  It sounds like a hardware problem. Not a software problem. Make sure you set the jumpers to show one as master, and the other as secondary.

Answer (score 0):

I removed both my SATA drives and rebooted, then put them back in.  After that, I set their boot order, and then just waited.  I got a purple screen that allowed me to choose to boot up Windows.  I just waited like a minute or two without touching anything and it booted into Linux.  Thank you all for your help!